# Navigate away script not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

So, making an web portal for work.  Boss wants me to log the user out if they navigate away from the page.  Found this tutorial: http://kbeezie.com/cross-browser-exit-pop/

I used the jquery example and inserted it into a couple pages to test it out.  I'm using asp.net/C# for development.  Here's the basic layout of the page, including my script:

```
<%@ Page ... %>
<asp:Content .. > </asp:Content>
<asp:Content .. >

   //my navigate away function
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function PopIt() {
         return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {
         window.onbeforeunload = PopIt;
          $("a").click(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
      });
   </script>

   <div>
      <table></table>
      //other stuff
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

When I click a link on our web portal, the navigate away script works, it doesn't pop up because we're clicking on an internal link.  But, if I keep navigating around on the site, after 2 or 3 clicks eventually if I click on an internal link it will ask me if I'm sure I want to leave.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Edit:  We have jquery referenced on every page, so this is not the issue.

Edit:  Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVUbP/1/) that works.  When you click on the link nothing happens but when you navigate away it prompts.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting the issue you describe, but I don't see how that code will react to you leaving the portal.  It will make *every* link remove the `onbeforeunload` handler, whether local or not.

Comment: We don't have any links on our page that go to an external website, that's why this solution works for us because it catches everything (going to Google, closing the browser, etc.)

Comment: Are the links that trigger the unload to eventually happen when it is not suppose to, links that are rendered in a master page content, or a different page rendering?

Comment: Some are in the page itself (via `<asp:HyperLink>`) and some are generated on other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a week or so of trying everything I gave up.  A couple days later one of my coworkers mentioned to me that one of our base classes that we were inheriting from had a script blocker function running `OnPreInit`.

I had long suspected that somewhere in our large codebase something was overriding my `OnBeforeUnload` functionality, but when I searched for the uses of `OnBeforeUnload` I found nothing.  As it turns out I never found the script blocker because someone thought it was a great idea to name it something nondescript!

After overriding the script blocker the original code worked.

Answer (score 1):

Since some of the links are generated then they won't be on the page when you assign the event handler that overrides the `onbeforeunload` handler.  Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PopIt() {
        return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = PopIt;
        $("document").on("click", "a", function () {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        });
    });
</script>
```

It will capture all link clicks, whether the links are on the page at the time the script runs or not.

Comment: This still isn't working.  I still get a dialog box when clicking on links.  Could it be possible I have my script tags in the wrong spot or something?  Don't know what else could be wrong.

Comment: That should handle all `a` tags on the page.  You don't have iframes on the page with links in them do you?  Without seeing the whole page it's difficult to guess what the problem could be.

Comment: Yea I know that's what I was worried about when I was starting to post this.  No frames on the page.  I'm about 90% sure that ASP.Net is messing something up.